# How to get statistics from Google AdSense for a specific URL from website?

Tags: google-ads-api, adsense, adsense-api

How to get statistics such as the number of clicks and the amount of income per URL from my site?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093729/query-google-adsense-data-by-url

Comment: and one more similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517780/get-the-total-earnings-from-a-specific-url-using-the-adsense-management-api?rq=1